# Why does XSLT code sometimes not get formatted automatically?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

The pretty formatting that usually happens automatically for XSLT code sometimes does not work.

It appears that when a question is tagged with the general [xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xslt) tag, all is well.  However, when an asker only uses the version-specific XSLT tags, [xslt-1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xslt-1.0) or [xslt-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xslt-2.0), no pretty code formatting occurs throughout the question or answers.  **Rather than require an asker to always add the general xslt tag to the question, can the code consider both xslt-1.0 and xslt-2.0 to be valid triggers for XSLT formatting?**

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24247204/290085) is an example of a question where there was no syntax highlighting of the XSLT code until after I edited it to add the general xslt tag.

Comment: The solution @Shog9 provided is the best solution but for future visitors of this question: You can force prettify formatting by [using the `<-- language: lang-xml --> ` hint](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/158100)